# Style Manager: Individual border for mjml elements ( border left,border right, border bottom, border top)

Tags: reactjs, gjs, grapesjs

**Used packages Details:**

1. "grapesjs": "^0.20.2",
2. "grapesjs-mjml": "^1.0.3",

I trying get individual border for mjml element section **(mj-section)**
while select mj-section i need to show individual border styles under decoration section,
This feauture is really important kind check and update.

**Expected Result:**
[image]
**(Its used in old version )**

---

**Actual Result:**
 
![image](https://github.com/GrapesJS/grapesjs/assets/84056393/addde92a-2552-4e36-899b-a1a510d047b6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here Initialy reset stylemanager sectors array, then added needed style properties inside the sectors array. I make it as custom plugin .People who need custom style manager use this .
https://gist.github.com/mkandanmk7/8accda4816de472e9a42cc9888fe9a08
[image]